# Centering (vertical and horizontal) and spacing span elements inside of a div element despite media query

Tags: html, css

I started working on [this](https://harrisj09.github.io/portfolio/) recently; See the part where it says "contact work about". Using my desktop it looks centered (1920 x 1080), but when I use this on my laptop it isn't centered and leans more towards the right. What can I do in order to make this centered and each separate element on the same line with some space between each of them?

Heres the HTML part

```
<div id="nav-base">
  <span id="contact">Contact</span>
  <span id="work">Work</span>
  <span id="about">About</span>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS part that affects those **`<span>`** elements (I'm using **[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)** for responsive design)

```
@media (min-width: 1281px) { 
.... /*Rest of the code for the site*/

/*
All values are the same for each media query
*/
#nav-base>span {
  color: rgb(197, 197, 197);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 375px;
  font-size: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 90px;
}
```

Comment: Please include all of the relevant HTML and CSS here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site. For instance, you mention you're using media queries, but there are no media queries in your CSS that you've shared.

Comment: I added a media query but I feel its unnecessary to add since everything is basically the same. The HTML and CSS I added is relevant, I'm just asking people to go look at the part of the site that shows the problem I'm having.

Comment: You might want to read the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use flex on the div and remove the left margin from the span items and add a minor one like:

```css
#nav-base {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
  ...
}
#nav-base > span {
  margin: 0 20px;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the `margin-left: 375px;` - If you want it to be responsive the margin shouldn't be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to learn css grids, this helps a lot with styling things like this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/.

Look at the code below for a css grids way of doing this easily.

```css
 #nav-base {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 }
 
 #nav-base>span {
    color: rgb(197, 197, 197);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 36px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 90px;
    place-self: center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="nav-base">
  <span id="contact">Contact</span>
  <span id="work">Work</span>
  <span id="about">About</span>
</div>
```